# Gradle : one jar per classes directory

Tags: java, gradle

I generated mutiple classes folders and I try to generate a Jar for each of them.
I stored those folders in a `classesDirectories` var.

Here is the task I tried :

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    ext.counter= 0; 
    classesDirectories.each { aDir ->
        counter++
        baseName (counter.toString()) +".jar"
        from "${aDir}"
        destinationDir project.buildDir
    }
}
```

The problem is that I only find one Jar (the last generated one).

How can I generate a jar for each classes directory ?

Comment: You might be interested in my [java flavours plugin](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours) where each flavour has its own source directory and compile, jar, test etc tasks

Answer (score 0):

The `Jar` task can produce only one archive.

You could declare one Jar task per class directory, using dynamic task creation:

```
// Main wrapper task that will depend on each source-x tasks
task sourcesJar

ext{
    // class directories 
    classesDirectories = ['externalClasses/app1', 'externalClasses/app2', 'externalClasses/app2']
    // counter for incrementing task name
    taskNum = 0
}
classesDirectories.each { srcDir ->
    taskNum++
    def task = task "source-${taskNum}" (type: Jar) {
        baseName "${taskNum}.jar"
        from file("$srcDir")
        destinationDir project.buildDir
    }
    sourcesJar.dependsOn(task)
}
```

Then you just have to execute `./gradlew sourcesJar`: this will trigger execution of all `source-x` tasks and produce the expected jars:

```
11:05:20: Executing task 'sourcesJar'...

> Task :source-1
> Task :source-2
> Task :source-3
> Task :sourcesJar
```